# How to delete an item that is connected to a foreignkey django?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem adding a delete functionality to my simple django project which is a todoapp. The problem is when i press the delete button it redirect me to the same page but the item is not deleted. Can someone explain to me what is happening on my code?

This is my code solution but still does not work.

This is my views.py

```
def index(request, id):

ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
p = request.POST

if request.method == "POST":

    if p.get("save"):

        for item in ls.item_set.all():

            item_id = str(item.id)

            if "clicked" == p.get("c" + item_id):
                item.complete = True
            else:
                item.complete = False

            if p.get("text" + item_id) in p:
                item.text = p.get("text" + item_id)

            if p.get("d" + item_id) == "delete": # Solution
                item.delete()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" % ls.id)

            item.save()

    elif p.get("add"):

        new_item = p.get("new")

        if new_item:
            ls.item_set.create(text=new_item)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("<strong>Invalid Input</strong>")

return render(request, "todoapp/index.html", {"ls": ls})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ToDoList(models.Model):

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):

    toDoList = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'todoapp/base.html' %}

{% block title %}View List{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>{{ls.name}}</h2>
    <form method="post", action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for item in ls.item_set.all%}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" name="d{{item.id}}" value="delete"> <!-- Solution -->

                        <input type="checkbox" name="c{{item.id}}" value="clicked" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" {% if item.complete %} checked {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="text{{item.id}}" value="{{item.text}}" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">   
            <button name="add", value="add", type="submit", class="btn btn-success">Add New</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="new" value="" class="form-control">
            
        </div>
        <br>
        <button name="save", value="save", type="submit", class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem is after deleting the item instance you're saving it again so it doesn't make any difference. You should consider adding an `if-else` block. In the `if` block, delete the instance if the condition `p.get("d" + item_id) == "delete"` matches and in the `else` block, save the `item` instance.

Comment: I already tried doing that but still it redirect you to the same page but the item that i want to delete is still there

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you include the delete logic inside another 'if' clause.

```
if p.get("delete"):

    for item in ls.item_set.all():

        item_id = str(item.id)

        if p.get("d" + item_id) == "delete": # Solution
            item.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" % ls.id)
```

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve as the end result. Here, only one item would get deleted (the item for which 'delete' button was clicked).